# ADB Connection to Samsung smart tv

Tags: adb, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I am trying to install third party apk to Samsung android smart tv...

**1)** I've turn on Developer mode in Apps and put my computer ip address there.

**2)** I'm runing this commands in terminal (mac os, the latest version of sdk-tools)

```
adb kill-server && adb start-server && adb connect 192.168.1.237:26101 && adb devices
```

Getting this:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
connected to 192.168.1.237:26101
List of devices attached
192.168.1.237:26101 device
```

**3)** And run:

```
adb install ./my.apk**
```

And got this:

```
Performing Push Install
adb: error: connect failed: closed
- waiting for device -
```

p.s. almost every command failed with `error: closed`
(i've tried adb shell, adb logcat, and so on...)

What next step to try ? Is port 26101 correct? (I've also tried port 5555, but get `Connection refused`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but I haven't seen any Samsung Smart TV running Android. Samsung has their own operating system (Tizen) but, as far I know you can't install apk apps, also you cannot install apps using adb (in Tizen is named SDB), instead of SDB you need to use the Tizen SDK + Tizen Studio to pair your PC, sign your app (.wgt extension) and install it using the SDB

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible now install .wgt extension to tizen os version tv-2.4?  (I have Samsung tv UE60KU6072 and get a lot of errors with tizen studio ("error: closed")...

Comment: Are you trying to install using Tizen Studio 2.x? If so, please follow this guide and try to install the wgt using the 1.3 version (remember to generate the certificates and upload them to the tv, using the right click on the device explorer & selecting 'allow to install apps')